# Quotient ring example

Tags: ring-theory

> Theorem: Let $R$ be a ring and let $I$ be an ideal of $R.$
>
> Define $\frac{R}{I}=\left \{ a+I \mid a \in R \right \}$
>
> with binary operation :
>
> $\left ( a+I \right )+\left ( b+I \right )=\left ( a+b \right )+I$
> and
> $\left ( a+I \right )\cdot \left ( b+I \right )=\left ( a\cdot b \right )+I$

Then, $\left ( \frac{R}{I},+,\cdot  \right )$ is a ring under the binary operations called the quotient ring.

Here is an example that I would appreciate clarifications

> Example:
>
> $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{4\mathbb{Z}}=\left \{ 0+4\mathbb{Z},1+4\mathbb{Z},2+4\mathbb{Z},3+4\mathbb{Z} \right \}$
>
> $\left ( 2+4\mathbb{Z} \right )\cdot \left ( 3+4\mathbb{Z} \right )=\mathbf{6+4\mathbb{Z}=2+4\mathbb{Z}}$

How is it possible for $2$ to be equivalent to $6$ in the highlighted bold? The elements $6$ is in the group of integers without mod $4$ defined.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "without mod 4 defined?" By definition, $2\equiv 6 (mod 4)$.

Comment: In a quotient ring, lots of elements that start out unequal correspond to the same element of the quotient ring. Do you know the definition of the sets $6+4\Bbb Z$ and $2+4\Bbb Z$? Can you see from that definition that they're the same set?

Comment: @rnrstopstraffic I mean that the group of integers does not have the binary operation mod(4). If it did, the notation used would have been$\mathbb{Z}_{4}$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: edit:$(\mathbb{Z},+_{4})$

Comment: Congruence modulo 4 isn't a binary operation; it's an equivalence relation.  $a\equiv b\text{ (mod 4)}$ if and only if $a-b\in 4\mathbb{Z}$. Note that this is identical to the definition for two cosets being equal: $a+I=b+I$ if and only if $a-b\in I$.

Comment: Basically, all elements of the ring in the denominator are equal to zero in the quotient ring, so since 6=4+2 and the denominator of the quotient ring is 4Z, since 4 is in 4Z 4=0, thus 6=0+2=2. I think this is what you are asking

Answer (score 1):

$6+4\mathbb{Z}=2+4+4\mathbb{Z}=2+4\mathbb{Z}$